# UpdateDataInstance not updating data?

Tags: c1-cms

I have tried to use the UpdateDataInstance function to update some global data using an xslt-function. I get no error but the data is not updated. Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

If I simplify my code as much as possible it looks like this:

```
<f:function xmlns:f="http://www.composite.net/ns/function/1.0" name="Composite.Community.OpenID.Users.UpdateDataInstance">
  <f:param name="Location" value="My city" />
</f:function>
```

I run the code before the `<xsl:template match="/">` tag in my xslt function.

Thanks in advance

-- Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After moving the code to after the `<xsl:template match="/">` it worked very well.